# pass two parameters using java8 stream().map to call service method

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I've the below service which works correctly with `Java8`

```
List<ReportCount> getReportDetails(List<String> statusList);

statusList.add(Arrays.asList("SUCCESS"));
statusList.add(Arrays.asList("CANCELLED"));    
statusList.add(Arrays.asList("ON_HOLD","INPROGRESS"));

statusList.stream()
          .map(reportService::getReportDetails)
          .forEach(e -> reportMap.put("report_" + reportMap.size(), e));
```

How to pass 1 more parameter using above code for below method.

```
String id="CA";
List<ReportCount> getReportDetails(List<String> statusList, String id);
```

Could anyone please help. Thanks

Comment: Use a lambda expression. Unless your `statusList` truly is a list of lists, even the first parameter doesn’t match.

Comment: statusList is having the list of statuses

Comment: Then you want to pass the whole list, not each element, to getReportDetails(). Why are you using raw types? What it the type of the first argument of getReportDetails()?

Comment: `statusList` is getting passed. Above code is working already with `getReportDetails(List statusList)`. when i add 1 more parameter, unable to pass inside map, it throws error

Comment: Impossible. There's something you're not telling us.

Comment: Where is the `id` parameter value *supposed* to come from? How do you expect us to help with the syntax, when you don't even tell us where the value is?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention type of list and id

Comment: Beyond the question, you shouldn't use `forEach` to put elements in a map. Use `collect(Collectors.toMap(...))` instead.

Comment: I wonder if this could be done with a Runnable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by **not** using raw types:

```
List<ReportCount> getReportDetails(List<String> statusList, String id);
```

Then use a lambda expression:

```
List<List<String>> listOfStatusList = new ArrayList<>();
listOfStatusList.add(Arrays.asList("SUCCESS"));
listOfStatusList.add(Arrays.asList("CANCELLED"));    
listOfStatusList.add(Arrays.asList("ON_HOLD","INPROGRESS"));

String someId = ...;

listOfStatusList.stream()
                .map(statusList -> reportService.getReportDetails(statusList, someId))
```

Comment: You should show dummy declaration of `someId` to highlight that it has to come from somewhere, e.g. `String someId = /*assign value*/;`

Comment: @Andreas indeed. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to:

1) map to an Object array adding original data as entry 0, then add extra parameters to the other entries

2) map again, this time use the data in the Object array casting back to the specific types added in the first mapping.